# Laravel 5 - Sending a variable through an href with a route inside

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code:

```
@foreach($clientes as $cli)
  <tr>

      <td>{{$cli->id}}</td>
      <td>{{$cli->nome}}</td>
      <td>{{$cli->bi}}</td>
      <td>{{$cli->telefone}}</td>
      <td>{{$cli->morada}}</td>
      <td>{{$cli->cp}}</td>
      <td>{{$cli->email}}</td>
      <td>{{$cli->valido}}</td>
      //<td><a href="{{$url = route('a_clientes'){{$cli->id}}"></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

I want to edit the line with the //.

What I need to do is create a new column in the table with an `href` inside that redirects the user to a page where he can change the record of the `$cli` with that id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is a little off...

```
<td><a href="{{ route('a_clientes', $cli->id ) }}">Edit</a></td>
```

Comment: working ! thank you sir, i knew my problem was in syntax just needed the help writing it :D

Comment: how can it work for you but not work for me? I don't understand what I am doing wrong :(